# How to make sure Certificate is safe in WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication, certificate, x509

WCF supports to use certificate to authenticate Client. If a malicious user steals client's certificate and creates connection with Server. Can Server know this? If we install certificate to Microsoft Certificate Store, how to make sure it is safe? I could easily read the certificate in store by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Server know this?

no.

> If we install certificate to Microsoft Certificate Store, how to make sure it is safe?

you can't.

Certificates themselves don't solve secret leaking problem. They provide better security on a transport, better UX when authenticating on remote server, but they can leak as easy as passwords (ok, not that easy, but can). Such issues are solved using different techniques, like storing the certificate on a smart card where you need to have both, a card itself and PIN/Password to access the card. These are out-of-band solutions the certificate is not aware about, thus you can't tell whether the key is secure or not.